# Health check, ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, health-check

In my work I was asked to implement health checks into an ASP.NET Web API 2 written in C#. I have searched but all the documentation is for ASP.NET Core and its implementation, does anyone know how to implement health check featurs in the classic / full .NET Framework?

Comment: Probably create a dummy reachable end point that also tests dependent external resources (like database connections). Then create some external event (recurring and/or manually triggered) that tests this end point and reports results.

Comment: app.metrics has healthchecks.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Igor. Here's a concrete application of what he suggested (obviously, there are other ways to do this, but this is the best way I know how to keep it clear and honor separation of concerns):

1. Create a new controller. In this example, I'll call it HealthController
2. Add an action to the controller, and annotate it with [HttpGet]
3. Place logic inside the action that checks for the stability of external dependencies. For example, if disk access is critical for your API, run a test or two to make sure that the disk is responding like you need it to. If you need to be able to query a database, make a sample query, and make sure it's successful. This part is completely custom and really depends on your API and how it needs to perform.

```
public class HealthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Check()
    {
        // Add logic here to check dependencies
        if (/* successful */)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        return InternalServerError(); // Or whatever other HTTP status code is appropriate
    }
}
```

4. Have an external service issue a GET request to your endpoint (currently at https://whatever.your.domain.is/Health/Check) and report back when it doesn't receive 200 OK for some amount of time.

I've used [Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-health-checks.html) in the past and I've been happy with it. There are going to be other services out there that will do this for you, but I don't have any experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostic.HealthChecks` packages are compatible with .Net Framework and can be used as per the existing documentation. The missing piece is just a handler to handle requests to the endpoint and run the health checks.

I've recently implemented health checks in an application targeting `net472` as follows:

- Create implementations of `IHealthCheck` as documented for an ASP.Net Core application.
- Add a handler for the health endpoint. In my case I created a terminal OwinMiddleware:

  ```cs
  public class HealthCheckHandler : OwinMiddleware
  {
      private readonly HealthCheckService _healthCheckService;

      public HealthCheckHandler(OwinMiddleware next, HealthCheckService healthCheckService)
          : base(next)
      {
          _healthCheckService = healthCheckService;
      }

      public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
      {
          var report = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync(context.Request.CallCancelled); 

          if (report.Status == HealthStatus.Unhealthy)
          {
              context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
          }

          context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
          await context.Response.WriteAsync(report.ToJsonString());
      }
  }
  ```
- Add the health checks to your DI Container per the existing documentation. In my case I configured Autofac by:

  ```cs
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<MyHealthCheck>(MyCheck);

  builder.Populate(services);
  ```

  That last method is in the `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package.
- In the application startup, resolve an instance of `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckService` from the DI container and then call :

  ```cs
  app.Map("/health", x => x.Use(typeof(HealthCheckHandler), healthCheckService));
  ```